# How to automate button click in angular 4 app?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, oauth, google-oauth

Want to execute code inside `this.auth2.attachClickHandler` without the button click.
Not able to figure out

**Requirement**
Want to go for google authorization when the page renders without having to click any button.
Code is working and fetching me the google auth token when I click google sign in button.
But how to execute it without clicking the button.

**CODE**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
declare const gapi: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'google-signin',
  template: '<button id="googleBtn">Google Sign-In</button>'
})
export class GoogleSigninComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  private clientId: string = 'XXXXXX';

  private scope = [
    'profile',
    'email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly'
  ].join(' ');

  public auth2: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    //this.googleInit();
  }

  public googleInit() {
    let that = this;
    gapi.load('auth2', function () {
      that.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: that.clientId,
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        scope: that.scope
      });
      that.attachSignin(that.element.nativeElement.firstChild);
    });
  }
  public attachSignin(element) {
    let that = this;
    console.log(this.auth2);
    let x = document.querySelector('#googleBtn')//.click();
    console.log(x);
    //Execute code inside this attachClickHandler automatically
    this.auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
      function (googleUser) {
        console.log(googleUser);
        let profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log('Token || ' + googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);
        console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
        console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
      }, function (error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
      });
  }

  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
    //console.log('ElementRef: ', this.element);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.googleInit();

  }

}
```

Can anybody guide me on this?I am still learning. Thanks

Comment: calling function on ngOnInit didn't work?

Comment: No Friend - it did not work on ngOninit - function is waiting for button click

Comment: even if you implement OnInit while exporting your class like 
export class GoogleSigninComponent implements OnInit{ } ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you reach that page, you can keep a query parameter in the url like ?google=true and in the ngAfterViewInit you could check if the query parameter is set, if yes then you could call the google auth otherwise dont

For more understanding on accessing query params

https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular-passing-optional-query-parameters-to-route/

Comment: Deepak - function - attachSignin - is executing -  execution stops when I reach to this function  => this.auth2.attachClickHandler.  This function is using googleUser in its callback  -  How I get googleUser without calling this function

Comment: place document.querySelector('#googleBtn').click(); after the click handler so as a result the click function attached to is called